# Pointwise convergence with function valued on extended real line

Tags: real-analysis

I just want to clarify if we allow $f(x)=\infty$ when we define $f_n(x) \to f(x)$ pointwise. Or $f_n \to f$ would imply that $f(x) \neq \infty$ (this I assume is different from boundedness?).

Example: $f_n(x)=(1-|x|)n,-1\le x \le 1$ and $f=0$ otherwise. In this case, $f$ takes infinite values on $(-1,1)$. In this case, can we say $f_n$ converge to $f$ pointwise?

Comment: For downvote: I have made edits to clarify the question. Please let me know if it is still unclear.

Comment: This is question about definitions. There is no proof or counter-example involved. In some circumstances Mathematicians allow infinite values but in some other circumstances they don't.